# operation with bit in python

Tags: python, bit, valueconverter

I have the formula: (short) (0xF800 | (N & 0x7ff)). With the help of C/CPP/C# I changed the sign of the eight-bit numbers (eg 1202 numbers to -846). In Python this trick is not working. How do I get the same result?

Comment: the number is not eight-bit, it is eleven bit! typo

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish? Why do you need to set the upper five bits to 1? Do you realize that with a short, 0xF800 | (N & 0x7FF) == 0xF800 | N?

Answer (score 2):

Integers in Python have an infinite length. To make a negative number you need to set the top bit, but there's no "top" with Python - you can't do this with bit manipulation. What you *can* do is convert a positive number to negative with subtraction.

```
bits = 0xf800 | (N & 0x7ff)
if bits & 0x8000:
    bits -= 0x10000
```

Since you already know the top bit is set, this simplifies:

```
bits = (0xf800 | (N & 0x7ff)) - 0x10000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with C(++) types you will need to use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) or [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) modules

This method uses struct to pack the integer into a byte string, then unpack it as a different type.

```
>>> import struct
>>> N = 1202
>>> struct.unpack('h', struct.pack('H',0xf800|(N & 0x7ff)))[0]
-846
```

This method uses ctypes which has an internal representation similar to what you'd have in C(++)

```
>>> from ctypes import c_short
>>> N = 1202
>>> c_short(0xf800|(N & 0x7ff)).value
-846
```

Comment: what is faster ? ctypes or struct ?

Comment: performance is probably not the important issue here so much as what you're going to do with the data once you've got it. If you're just converting  one value at a time, and don't need to write out the raw byte strings then ctypes will be fine. Otherwise you probably want struct.

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone will need:

From ctypes import c_short
C_short (0xF800 | (N & 0x7ff)). Value